# Implicit function derivation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem

I have function $h(x,y)=e^{xy^2-1}+\log{\frac{x}{y}}-1$ and I have to find if a function $y=f(x)$ around $[1,1]$ exists. I have to check some conditions in order to find out if $y=f(x)$, $h(1,1)=0,\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}(1,1)\not =0$ and finally wheter $h(x,y)\in C^1(U)$,where $U$ is neighbourhood(not sure if it is correct term in English) $U=B([1,1],\epsilon )$. Since I want to be safe and I don't want to think too much during test, can I choose really small $\epsilon$ so the $\frac{x}{y}$ in logarithm is not negative or zero?

Comment: For $h(x,y)=e^{xy^2-1}+\log{\frac{x}{y}}$, $h(1,1)=e^{0}+\log{1}=1>0$. So it does not satisfies the condition $h(1,1)=0$.

Comment: I forgot to write 1, but my question was rather general, I wrote this as example. I don't want the solution but the the condition of the function being Differentiable .

Comment: If h(x,y) is given as defined, then what do you mean by "find if a function y=f(x) exists"? $h(x_1,y_1)$ gives a particular value, and assuming h is differentiable around the point, Taylor's series would give an approximation for h. $y$ is independent, right?

Comment: @tpb261 What I mean is that according to implicit function theorem, several conditions have to be met. I need to check them if I want to find out if the implicit function really exists, and my question is about one of the conditions, I apologize if if it is not clear as my English is not that good.

Answer (score 0):

Set $x=1+\epsilon u$ and $y=1+\epsilon v$ and expand $h(1+\epsilon u,1+\epsilon u)$ in $\epsilon$:

$$h(1+\epsilon u,1+\epsilon u)=(2u+v)\epsilon+O(\epsilon^2)$$

Thus we obtain:

$$v=-2u \implies (y-1)=-2(x-1) \implies y(x)=-2x+3$$.